# JS receiving NaN when trying to add number to a variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to code a roll dice game, but I constantly get a NaN number in my console.

```
    var dice, score;

function rollDice() {

  dice = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  dice !== 1 ? score += dice : score = 0;

  return score;
}

var hey = rollDice();
console.log(hey);
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: sorry @hackerrdave, I am trying to find out why i get the NaN value instead a score

Comment: initializing variables is a good idea

Comment: Why are `dice` and `score` defined outside of the function?

Comment: @FelixKling well I have declared these outside the function so thier scope is global i can move them inside function scope,

Comment: @ASDFGerte i though that you can assign or initialise the var at any point with any value, as in js if you assign a string it will be a string or number it will be a int, is that correct

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a default value to the `score` variable, like `score = 0`, because now it's undefined. Example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/leusrox/z01nLg4t/)

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `score` is never initialized to a value, so when performing this operation:

```
score += dice
```

It is really performing:

```
undefined += 3
```

And `undefined` + a number is always `NaN`.
Try initializing `score` to `0`:

```
var dice = 0;
var score = 0;
```

```js
var dice = 0;
var score = 0;

function rollDice() {

  dice = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  dice !== 1 ? score += dice : score = 0;

  return score;
}

var hey = rollDice();
console.log(hey);
```

Comment: @Baruch - adding `undefined` and a number always results in `NaN` - your link does not disprove that...

Comment: Did you run the script? And yes, `typeof` will return `undefined` but the variable will be declared as a number (not like types matter in JavaScript anyway).

Comment: Run the script in my answer that you downvoted and tell me that it doesn't work.

Comment: "ternary is causing NaN" is not a true statement, that's why it was downvoted

Comment: @Baruch: This answer is correct. Your example doesn't seem to prove anything (or I fail to see what it is supposed to prove). *"but the variable will be declared as a number"* Variables don't have types, only values do. `var score;` initializes `score` with `undefined`, and `undefined + <number>` is undeniably `NaN`.... I don't understand which part of this answer you think is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

Your terniary is what's causing the NaN. Try this.

```
score = dice !== 1 ? (dice + 1) : 0;
```

Example: https://repl.it/NKul/1

**EDIT**

Fixed true condition for terniary.

Comment: *"Your terniary is what's causing the NaN"* Not quite. It's the `score += dice` that causes `NaN` to be assigned to `score`, which, admittedly, is part of the conditional expression.